# Persistent Cookie in Classic ASP

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, persistent

I am having an issue with keeping persistent cookies.

**Problem:**

With below code, I am able to create a cookie and keep it during the entire browser session.
However, when I close the browser the cookie is removed after a few seconds.

**Points that have been checked:**

- The browser settings have been checked, and are configured to allow
  cookies. (first and 3thd party).
- Multiple browsers have been used to test, it occurs in all (Chrome,
  IE8-9-10-11, Safari, Firefox, Opera)
- Multiple Servers (MS 2000, 2003, 2008)

So I've got the following code in classic ASP:

```
Response.Cookies("user").expires= DateAdd("m",1,now())'looks like:  5/29/2014 3:53:13 PM'
Response.Cookies("user")("org")=request("org")
```

**In short:**
**My persistent Cookie keeps getting removed!**

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Comment: Change your browser settings. It set to clear cache and Temporary files upon closing.

Comment: Good point @AllBlond +1

Comment: @AllBlond - thanks for the tip, it solved my problem, browser was configured to "Delete browsing history on exit", which included the removal of cookies. Which ofcourse overrides the settings to keep cookies.

Comment: @AllBlond You should add that as an answer, so the OP can accept it.

Comment: OP already posted it under his name. No need for me to duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution to the problem:**
The browser was configured to *"Delete browsing history on exit"*, which included the removal of cookies.

This option overrides any settings to keep cookies.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```vb
Response.Cookies("user").expires= DateAdd("m",1,now())

if request("org")<>"" then
  Response.Cookies("user")("org")=request("org")
end if
```

Comment: And what exactly will that do when browser deleting files upon closing?